# Confused about alloc and release

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, allocation

I'm a little confused about Objective-C and allocating/releasing objects.

If I do this:

```
NSString *myString;

if([someString isEqualToString: @"test1"]){
    myString = @"got 1";
}else{
    myString = @"got 2";
}
```

Do I have to release `myString` after that?

And the same with self-defined objects:

```
myOwnObject *someObject = [someArray objectAtIndex: 1];

myButton.label1.text = someObject.name;
```

Do I have to release `someObject`?

The reason why I'm asking is that I get memory-leaks in a method and I can't find where it is. So I'm trying to figure out whether I do the alloc/release stuff correctly.
The leak occurs on a NSPlaceholderString (I guess that's somewhere hidden in my NIB-File).

Also - if I have an object, allocate it, but only use some of the properties, but DO a release of every property on dealloc - will this cause memory leaks?

Sorry - hope my questions do make at least *some* sense :)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Listen to me. **THIS IS THE ONLY RULE THAT MATTERS.**

---

#### If you use a method with *"copy", "alloc", "new", or "retain"* in the name

### You *own* the object and *MUST* later *release or autorelease* it.

#### If you don't:

### Don't!

#### But don't expect the object to stick around outside of that scope, because *you don't own it*.

It's that simple.

---

```
MyClass *foo = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[array addObject:foo];
[foo release];
```

Did you use "copy", "retain", "new", or "alloc"? Yes. Release it.

```
MyClass *someObject = [someArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Did you use "copy", "retain", "new", or "alloc"? No. Don't release it.

***BUT***

If you have an *instance variable* which you need to access *in other methods*:

```
ivar = [[someArray objectAtIndex:0] retain];
```

Then you're guaranteed it will stick around because you own it.

(Another way to handle this is with `@property (retain)` properties, because then you can do `self.ivar = someObject` and it'll retain it for you.)

But remember to release them in `-dealloc`!

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to release either of those. I usually `release` only objects that I `alloc`, such as this snippet:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", something];
// yadda yadda yadda some code...
[string release];
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, you don't need to release strings created with the @"" syntax.

On your second example, you should not have to release `someObject`. However, a problem could arise if your `dealloc` method in your `myOwnObject` class does not correctly release all of its instance variables.